# Django RestFramework group by

Tags: json, xml, django, django-rest-framework

My issue is related to the django-rest-framework and is about how to group elements.

This is my **serializers.py**

```py
from collaborativeAPP.models import *
from rest_framework import serializers

class VocabSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    term_word = serializers.CharField(source='term.word',read_only=True)
    kwdGroup = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    class Meta:
        model = Vocab
        fields = ('id','term_word', 'meaning','kwdGroup')

class TermSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    word = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Term
        fields = ('url', 'word')
```

The following *JSON* it's the actual result:

```
{"results":[
            {
                "id": 5,
                "term_word": "word1",
                "meaning": "Text1"
                "kwdGroup": "A"
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "term_word": "word2",
                "meaning": "Text2"
                "kwdGroup": "A"
            },
            {
                "id": 7,
                "term_word": "word3",
                "meaning": "Text3"
                "kwdGroup": "A"
            }
        ]}
```

As you can notice `kwdGroup` is a repetitive element that I which to group.

I would like to group by `kwdGroup`:

```
{"A":[
       {
        "id": 5,
        "term_word": "word1",
        "meaning": "Text1"
        },
        {
        "id": 6,
        "term_word": "word2",
        "meaning": "Text2"
        },
        {
        "id": 7,
        "term_word": "word3",
        "meaning": "Text3"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm looking for answers on http://www.django-rest-framework.org/ on the API guide but I'm having difficulties finding an approach to lead with it.
Do you share this same issue? Do you have any suggestions on how can i do this? Do you have any example that deals with element grouping using django-rest-framework?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how do you get your "actual" result? Please add the code of the view, or a query you use to get the data

Comment: Sylvain, for my question you don't need to evaluate the code. If you know the django RestFramework you just need to know if DjangoRestFrameWork provides or not this capability. There are several scripts that contribute to build this json ( serializer.py, models.py, views.py, urls.py ) and it doesn't make sense to show all of them. What i can show that could help is serializer which is now updated.

Comment: I ran into the same issue recently. I just avoided the serializer, and overrode the view's get method to produce the JSON output directly. I would like to know if there's a way to do it neatly with serializers. I actually had 2 levels of grouping to do.

Answer (score 8):

Let's assume that the `kwdGroup` field is the relation field to a model called `KeyWordGroup`.

The default `ListSerializer` uses the `to_representation` method to render a list of the serialized objects [rest_framework](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py) :

```
class ListSerializer(BaseSerializer):
     ...

    def to_representation(self, data):
        """
          List of object instances -> List of dicts of primitive datatypes.
        """
        # Dealing with nested relationships, data can be a Manager,
        # so, first get a queryset from the Manager if needed
        iterable = data.all() if isinstance(data, models.Manager) else data

        return [
            self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
        ]
```

We can modify the `ListSerializer` to group the results for example:

```
class VocabListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):

    def to_representation(self, data):
        iterable = data.all() if isinstance(data, models.Manager) else data
        return {
            kwdGroup: super().to_representation(Vocab.objects.filter(kwdGroup=kwdGroup))
            for kwdGroup in KeyWordGroup.objects.all()
        }
```

We can then use the modified `VocabListSerializer` with the `VocabSerializer`.

```
class VocabSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
...
    class Meta:
        list_serializer_class = VocabListSerializer
```

Comment: This gives me this error when used in a similar use-case: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type

Answer (score 3):

One way to achieve this is to use a [SerializerMethodField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield).  The below might be slightly different than your use case, but you can adopt accordingly.  There are other ways of achieving this as well, including overwriting `to_representation` methods, but they rely on messing with the inner workings of DRF more than is relevant here.

## models.py

```py
class Dictionary(Model):
    id = PrimaryKey


class Word(Model):
    dictionary = ForeignKey(Dictionary, related_name='words')
    word = Charfield()
    group = Charfield()
```

## serializers.py

```py
class WordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    word = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
            model = Word
            fields = ('word',)


class DictionarySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    group_a = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    group_b = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_group_a(self, instance):
        return WordSerializer(instance.words.filter(group='a'), many=True).data

    def get_group_b(self, instance):
        return WordSerializer(instance.words.filter(group='b'), many=True).data

    class Meta:
        model = Dictionary
        fields = ('group_a', 'group_b')
```

## An example

```py
>>> my_dictionary = Dictionary.objects.create()
>>> Word.objects.bulk_create(
        Word(word='arrow', group='a' dictionary=my_dictionary),
        Word(word='apple', group='a' dictionary=my_dictionary),
        Word(word='baby', group='b' dictionary=my_dictionary),
        Word(word='banana', group='b' dictionary=my_dictionary)
)
>>> serializer = DictionarySerializer(my_dictionary)
>>> print serializer.data
{
    'group_a': {
        'word': 'arrow',
        'word': 'apple'
    },
    'group_b': {
        'word': 'baby',
        'word': 'banana'
    },
}
```

Comment: Can you make this work with a dynamic amount of different groups?

Comment: It's working but It will increase response time a lot if you use nested serializer in this way.

Answer (score 0):

If the previously mentioned `VocabListSerializer` doesn't work, try this method:

```
class VocabListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    child:serializers.ModelSerializer

    def to_representation(self, data):

        iterable:Iterable[Sentence] = data.all() if isinstance(data, models.Manager) else data
        group_by_dict = {}
        for item in iterable : 
            kwdGroup_id = item.kwdGroup.id
            if kwdGroup_id in group_by_dict.keys ():
                group_by_dict[kwdGroup_id].append (self.child.to_representation(item))
            else : 
                group_by_dict [kwdGroup_id] = []

        return list(group_by_dict.values())

class VocabSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    ...
    class Meta:
        list_serializer_class = VocabListSerializer
```

Note that the `ListSerializer` must create a **list**. Returning a dict like the original question requested does not seem possible by just overriding `to_representation`. If you don't use

```
list(group_by_dict.values())
```

at the end, only the list of the foreign keys (`kwdGroup`) will be returned.