# How to shape response with 'group_by' query

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller

I want to create custom response object for an endpoint with using type of the object as keys.

Its a django back-end

model shape:

```py
Model.blahblah(
id = uuid
type = 'type1'
value = 'im batman!'
)
```

view:

```py
class HedesView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request):
        hedes = Event.objects.all().query
        events.group_by = ["type"]
        evento = QuerySet(query=hedes, model=Hedes)
        return Response(
            {
                "hedes": EventSerializer(evento, many=True).data 
            }
        )
```

response:

```
    hedes: [{...}, {...}, {...}]
```

how can I edit this response to be like this

```
hedes: {
   type1: [{...}, {...}],
   type2: [{...}]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with the group_by statement in Django, but in SQL, the underlying query language, GROUP BY returns one item for each type, which is not what you want.

To achieve the result you want, you would probably need to edit the EventSerializer's to_representation function, which is outlined in the answer to this question: [Django RestFramework group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31071702/django-restframework-group-by)

Answer (score 0):

In Django if you want to 'group_by' as in an SQL query you need to use the 'values' function of the ORM. The following block helped me with the topic:
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/12/06/how-to-create-group-by-queries.html