# Django Rest Framework group objects dynamically

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

My issue is related to Django RestFramework and how to dynamically group objects. The most similar answer I found came from Rex Salisbury [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31071702/django-restframework-group-by) but wasn't adaptable to *n* number of groups:

*models.py*

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Mix(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    percentage = models.FloatField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('product', 'ingredient')
```

*serializer.py*

```
class MixSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Mix
        fields = ('product', 'liquid', 'percentage')
```

*views.py*

```
class MixView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Mix.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MixSerializer
```

This is an example of the structure I'm currently getting from the API:

```
[ 
    {
        "product": "White Russian",
        "ingredient": "Vodka",
        "percentage": 0.54
    },
    {
        "product": "White Russian",
        "ingredient": "Coffee Liquer",
        "percentage": 0.27
    },
    {
        "product": "White Russian",
        "ingredient": "Single Cream",
        "percentage": 0.19
    }
]
```

I've been trying to group these in a way which minimises the product name repetition, something like this,

```
{
    "product": "White Russian",
    "ingredients": {
        "Vodka": 0.54,
        "Coffee Liquer": 0.27,
        "Single Cream": 0.19
    }
}
```

by following documentation for [Nested Relationship](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships) but I'm no longer convinced this is the right course of action. I'm comfortable getting this data from object filters but unable to implement this alongside the serializers/views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note, according to your example you are grouping by product, so you are not looking for a `MixView` but for `ProductView`.

What you could do:

```
# Serializers
class MixSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    ingredient_name = serializers.CharField(source='ingredient.name')
    class Meta:
        model = Mix
        fields = ('ingredient_name', 'percentage')

class ProductSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    ingridients = MixSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('name', 'ingridients')

# Views
class ProductView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
```

Should give you something like:

```
{
    "name": "White Russian",
    "ingredients": [
        {"ingredient_name": "Vodka", "percentage" : 0.54},
        {"ingredient_name": "Coffee Liquer", "percentage" : 0.27},
        {"ingredient_name": "Single Cream", "percentage" : 0.19}
    ]
}
```

P.S. To make it non read only you will need to also implement `create` and `update` methods under ProductSerializer

Comment: This has helped a lot. I did, however, have to add an extra parameter `source='mix_set'` to the `ingredients` variable in order to get it mostly working. I'm now facing `Field name 'ingredient_name' is not valid for model 'Mix'.` which is unexpected so I'm triple checking the code.

Comment: Right, have to declare ingredient_name under mix, I edited the code 1 additional line `ingredient_name = serializers.CharField(source='ingredient.name')`