# Django Rest Framework custom serializer data

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I got a serializer response that looks like this:

```
"results": [
            {
                "property_name": "Villa",
                "username": "Ivan",
                "email": "ivan@mail.com",
                "start_date": "2022-01-05",
                "end_date": "2022-01-19"
            },
            {
                "property_name": "Villa",
                "username": "Ivan",
                "email": "ivan@mail.com",
                "start_date": "2022-02-16",
                "end_date": "2022-03-03"
            },
            {
                "property_name": "Villa",
                "username": "Ivan",
                "email": "ivan@mail.com",
                "start_date": "2022-02-11",
                "end_date": "2022-02-25"
            }
        ]
```

I wonder is it possible for the serializer response to look like this:

```
[
  {
    name: 'Ivan',
    email: 'ivan@mail.com',
    stays: [
      {
        "start_date": "2022-01-05",
        "end_date": "2022-01-19",
        "property_name: Villa"
      },
      {
        "start_date": "2022-02-16",
        "end_date": "2022-03-03",
        "property_name: Villa"
      },
      {
        "start_date": "2022-02-11",
        "end_date": "2022-02-25",
        "property_name: Villa"
      },
    ]
  }  
]
```

This is my model:

```
class PropertyReservation(BaseModelFields):
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    property = models.ForeignKey('property.Property', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey('user.UserModel', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

my serializer:

```
class PropertyReservationGuestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    property_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='property.name')
    username = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.username')
    email = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.email')

    class Meta:
        model = PropertyReservation
        fields = ('property_name', 'username',
                  'email', 'start_date', 'end_date')
```

I tried a few things and cant manage the serializer response to look like one in the example above. This was the best answer I found on the internet [Django RestFramework group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31071702/django-restframework-group-by) and still was not able to do it, on the first solution I got an error when I call the super() function: "super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type". On the second solution when I try to achieve what I want with using a SerializerMethodField, I got an error "object has no attribute 'filter'".

Do you have any suggestions on how can I do this? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

There is a one way to get your stays with SerializerMethodField

```
class StaySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PropertyReservation
        fields = ('start_date', 'end_date', 'property_name')


class PropertyReservationGuestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.get_full_name')
    email = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.email')
    stays = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_stays(self, obj):
        stays = PropertyReservation.objects.filter(user__email=obj.email)
        return StaySerializer(stays, many=True).data

    class Meta:
        model = PropertyReservation
        fields = ('name', 'email', 'stays')
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve with this PropertyreservationSerializer. When I overwrite my PropertyReservationGuestSerializer with yours I get the error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'propertyreservation_set'

Comment: it was a mock queryset. What is your relation between this 2 models ? How you can reach PropertyReservation objects via using PropertyReservationGuest object ?

Comment: I got only one model as you can see in my question and one serializer. If you are confused with PropertyReservationGuestSerializer name you can read it like PropertyReservationSerializer, I added guest in this name because I want it to return guests serializer response as I write in question

Comment: I see now. Answer edited.

Comment: Thank you very much man, you help me a lot!